# Meteor strikes again

Tags: word, cipher, story, anagram

Part of a phone call:

---

-...well why didn't you just say so?

-It wasn't as easy as you thought, Jack. All the power lines here were destro---

-I know...It's not like we're living on a different planet Mark..

-Haha, good one. But you see, a second meteor hit this area. The good news is it was much smaller. The bad news is, there are absolutely zero power stations working.

-So how did you--

-This is what I'm trying to tell you. I went inside this place which seems to have been a really old battery store, which had a ton of charged batteries, I have no idea why it was abandoned. I'm talking from my mobile phone right now.
The place also has a generator in case of emergency, which I've managed to get working with gas from my car. Listen, we don't have much time before the spaceship comes back. I've sent you an email, which you need to decrypt in order to see which part of the spaceship we need to---

-Hold on..did you say decrypt?

-They're monitoring everything on this planet, Jack.

-But then they'll know that it is encrypted.

-They're aliens, Jack.

-Oh. Yeah.

-Look, you don't have to decrypt it...just find the hidden message with the two keys I've included and I'll carry the rest otherwise. Just hurry up!

---

It seems he left a message for me in a part of his code he emailed me. Unfortunately, some of the text has been lost, so part of the message must be gone now. The following is the only thing saved. It's from the comments in his code.

```
Source code is written in one or more programming languages. 
The programming of artificially intelligent robots to suffice...
```

The two keys:

- $\pi \rightarrow$ English $\rightarrow$ yes and no
- 413111 $\rightarrow$ position $\rightarrow$ anagram

Comment: Any hints or places to start? (bumping old unanswered question)